# Logstash output to server with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I intend to run logstash on multiple clients, which in turn would submit their logstash reports to the elastic search on a server(a Ubuntu machine, say).

Thus there are several clients running logstash outputting their logs to the elastic search on a COMMON server.

Is this o/p redirection to a server possible with Logstash on the various clients?

If yes, what would the configuration file be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a "broker" to collect the outputs from each of the servers.

Here's a good tutorial:
http://logstash.net/docs/1.1.11/tutorials/getting-started-centralized